# how to combine 2 or more bridge tables in a single query

Tags: sql, database-design, query-optimization

i have the following tables:

Table: People (id, first, last, age, phone, etc . .)
Table: Roles (id, name)
Table: Skills (id, name)
Table: People_Roles (id, personID^, roleID^)
Table: People_Skills (id, personID^, skillID^)

```
^ = foreign key
```

I basically want a query that gives me the full result set of all people and their roles and there skills.

Person.First, Person.Last, Roles.Name, Skills.Name

Comment: This looks like homework

Comment: unfortunately not . . right now i am essentially running many queries (one per row) and its taking a long time so i am trying to merge all my queries into one query . .

Comment: @monksy Who cares if it's homework? A question is a question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT p.first, p.last, r.name, s.name
FROM People p
LEFT JOIN People_Roles pr
ON pr.personID = p.id
INNER JOIN Roles r
ON pr.roleID = r.id
LEFT JOIN People_Skills ps
ON ps.personID = p.id
INNER JOIN Skills s
ON ps.skillID = s.id
```

This query will select you all the people, even those without `Roles` or `Skills` assigned.

Comment: but if i do all inner joins if there is a person with a skill and not a role then it wont show a records.  I want to see all combinations. i thought this was an outer join ??

Comment: @oo I've written a comment about it :). Updated the answer for your pleasure.

Comment: this still only gives me rows where there is a skill or a role . .what if there is a person with no skill or row . . how will that show up ?

Comment: @oo that person will show up as a person with NULL in both Skill and Role names. As soon as we use LEFT JOIN it returns ALL the records from the left table that means People table.

Answer (score 0):

This query will work:

```
SELECT Person.First, Person.Last, Roles.Name, Skills.Name  
FROM People 
    LEFT JOIN People_Skills 
        ON People.id = People_Skills.personID
    INNER JOIN Skills
        ON People_Skills.skillID = Skills.id
    LEFT JOIN People_Roles 
        ON People.id = People_Roles.personID
    INNER JOIN Roles
        ON People_Roles.roleID = Skills.id
```

By the way, why your "bridge" tables have their own ID. I would just use a [compound key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) made of PersonID and the corresponding foreign key (skillsID or rolesID) to ensure that every pair can only be made once.

Comment: but if i do all inner joins if there is a person with a skill and not a role then it wont show a records.  I want to see all combinations. i thought this was an outer join ??

Comment: agreed but i guess i would need to deal with that in code . . or go back to my original method of having a seperate query for each bridge table per record in the people table . .

Comment: Do a where clause and compare "is Null" to remove the null rows you don't want.

Comment: And left joins would probably be better than full joins

Comment: Updated query to return full result set, as described.

Comment: i am trying to figure out if its worth it as i have about 10 different bridge tables . . coding it in a loop is definatley much simpler but not sure on performance . .

Comment: Performance wise, calling the DB 10 times will cost a lot more than calling it once and getting a larger result set, unless the result set is massive...

Comment: and there is also the complexity of parsing the results and renormalizing it in my object model as my object model is a Person object with an array of Skills and an array of Roles

Comment: There is always a tradeoff... you need to decide how much of one you are willing to accept.